Showing a Fourier series is continuously differentiable
Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a $2\pi$-periodic continuously differentiable function. Define Fourier coefficients:
$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$
$$c_n'=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f'(x)e^{-inx}dx$$
I showed that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inx}$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathbb R$ to $f$ by Weierstrass $M$-test and the fact that $c_n'=in c_n$.
Next, I showed that this series below converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathbb R$, and is $2\pi$-periodic.
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_{100n}|^2e^{inx}$$
I am struggling to show that this series is continuously differentiable. I am not sure where to start. How do I know that the derivative exists and is continuous?
I think the derivative exists because the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty in|c_{100n}|^2e^{inx}$ (uniformly) converges (since for each $n$ and $x$, $|in|c_{100n}|^2e^{inx}|\le\frac{|c_{100n}'^2|}{100^2|n|}$). Also this series is continuous because uniform limit of sequence of continuous functions is continuous...?

(i) There are indices "$100n$" in several coefficients; is that intentional? (ii) Are you asking how to show the Fourier series for $f'$ converges to $f'$? That doesn't seem to be true under the stated hypotheses....

@AndrewD.Hwang (i) Yes (ii) What I am missing?

(i) Ah. In that case my comment (ii) is probably irrelevant. <> If it matters, I had in mind a continuous function $g$ whose Fourier series fails to converge (I recall examples were discovered around 1970), and $f$ an integral of $g$.
